# How to have wordpress point to a different directory

Tags: wordpress

wordpress installation is at: http://www.domain.com/mainpage

but I want people to access this via http://www.domain.com

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect your users from your index.php file to the path where you want them to go.
using `header("Location:YOUR_PATH");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things (3 if you have fancy URLs).

First. Go to the settings panel in WordPress.  Make the "Site Address" http://www.domain.com.  Leave the "WordPress Address" alone -- it should remain http://www.domain.com/mainpage/

Second. Copy index.php from mainpage/ and place the copy in your root directory for www.domain.com.  Change:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

To:

```
require('./mainpage/wp-blog-header.php');
```

If you're using pretty URLs you may have to copy .htaccess as well -- Wordpress usually can do this for you when you change the Site Address.